# Structure of data for multilabel Classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a prediction problem where a user is having access to multiple Target and each access is having separate row. Below is the data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[12567,12567,12567,12568,12568],"UnCode":[LLLLLLL,LLLLLLL,LLLLLLL,KKKKKK,KKKKKK],
"CoCode":[1000,1000,1000,1111,1111],"CatCode":[1,1,1,2,2],"RoCode":["KK","KK","KK","MM","MM"],"Target":[12,4,6,1,6]
})

**Here ID is unique but can be repeated if user has accessed multiple targets and target can be repeated as well if accessed by different ID's**
```

I have converted this data to OHE and used for prediction using binary relevance, where my X is constant and target is varying.

**Problem I am facing with this approach is the data becomes sparse and number of features in my original data are around 1300.**

**Can someone suggest me whether this approach is correct or not and what other methods/approach I can use in this type of problem. Also is this problem can be treated as multilabel classification?**

Below is the input data for model

[image: Input for model]

Comment: You could do a cross decomposition on your original data and transform it to a more "compact" feature set while maintaining the original features. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSCanonical.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSCanonical

Comment: it's hard to answer this without knowing the meaning of the data columns

Comment: @cookiemaster: Column definition>>ID: Unique ID for employee, UnCode:Which org unit employee belongs to,  CoCode:Company code with in organization for internal use, RoCode: Which role employee is having(eg PMO, Interviewer etc), Target: Which application employee has access to. Hope this helps. Ask is to provide list of applications which a new employee can have access to based on historical data

Comment: @FarhoodET Can you please elaborate. Decomposition will be on OHE data or the original raw data?

Comment: @Lucy One-Hot-Encoding is actually a preprocessing step to transform your data into numeric representations. Then you could decompose your original features and reduce the number of features you have.